# How do I get a trendline to appear on my scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, trendline

I'm having trouble getting a trend line to appear with on a scatter plot of data structured the following way:

```
cohort count
  <chr>  <int>
1 1989       5
2 1990       7
3 1991       4
4 1992       4
5 1993       8
6 1994       7
```

This is the code I used to produce the plot:

```
ggplot(bipoc, aes(x = cohort, y = count)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: Set `cohort` to numeric.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thanks.